# Performance difference - Jackson ObjctMapper.writeValue(writer, val) vs ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(val)

Tags: jackson, objectmapper, jackson-databind, jackson2, fasterxml

Is there any significant performance difference between the following two?

```
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(searchResult);
response.getWriter().write(json);
```

vs

```
mapper.writeValue(response.getWriter(), searchResult);
```

Answer (score 1):

`writeValueAsString` JavaDoc says:

> Method that can be used to serialize any Java value as a String.
>   Functionally equivalent to calling writeValue(Writer,Object) with
>   StringWriter and constructing String, but more efficient.

So, in case, you want to write `JSON` to `String` is much better to use this method than [`writeValue`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#writeValue-java.io.Writer-java.lang.Object-). Both these methods use [`_configAndWriteValue`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#Z:Z_configAndWriteValue-com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator-java.lang.Object-).

In your case it is better to write `JSON` directly to `response.getWriter()` than generating `String` object and after that writing it to `response.getWriter()`.